# Creating a login page as a popup that makes the page turn blurry

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a login/register page, i would like it so when the user presses th 'register now' button on the home page, a popup in the same website appears but the back is transparent and dull, here is an example of what i mean as i don't know how to explain it,

http://www.crazely.com/graphic/login-page-design-samples-ui-and-cool-stuff/

also what i found on this page,

http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/javascript-centre.htm

Basically i would just like to know how to do this,

If possible i would like to keep away from javascript or j query as much as possible 
Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you want an actual blur, try out [CSS filter effects](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit). These only work in Webkit however, and they can be intensive (i.e. slow).

Your second example is just a semi-transparent black background laid on top of your actual page, which is much easier and simpler. Get a transparent PNG (from [here](http://www.1x1px.me/) for example) and use it as a background image for a large element that spans the entire page, then put your form on top of that element.

Both the blur technique and the semi-transparent background can be done CSS only, so you won't need either Javascript or jQuery for that, but creating a popup of any kind will probably require some minimal scripting.

Answer (score 0):

See, this is done using JavaScript:-
You copy the code and run it in the browser:-

```
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


 function SignUpForNewsletter()
{
DarkenPage();
ShowNewsletterPanel();
}

function ShowNewsletterPanel()
{
var newsletter_panel = document.getElementById('newsletter_panel');

// w is a width of the newsletter panel
w = 300;
// h is a height of the newsletter panel
h = 300;

// get the x and y coordinates to center the newsletter panel
xc = Math.round((document.body.clientWidth/2)-(w/2))
yc = Math.round((document.body.clientHeight/2)-(h/2))

// show the newsletter panel
newsletter_panel.style.left = xc + "px";
newsletter_panel.style.top  = yc + "px";
newsletter_panel.style.display = 'block';
}



 // this function puts the dark screen over the entire page
function DarkenPage()
{
var page_screen = document.getElementById('page_screen');
page_screen.style.height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight + 'px';
page_screen.style.display = 'block';
}


</script>

<style type="text/css">

body
{
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 }

 #page_screen
 {
 background-color:#000000;
 filter:alpha(opacity=80);
 opacity: 0.8;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 display:none;
 }

 #newsletter_panel
 {
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 border:1px solid #000000;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h2>
    <span style="font-family: Trebuchet MS">Blur test&nbsp;
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Sign up for newsletter!"        
    onclick="SignUpForNewsletter();"
     /></span></h2>
<div id="lipsum">

 </div>

<div id="page_screen">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div id="newsletter_panel" style="display:none;">
    Sign up for our
    <h3 style="color:#FF6600;">NEWSLETTER</h3>

    your email address :
    <input type="text" />
    <br />

    <input type="button" value="Sign up!" onclick="SignUp();" />
</div>
```